# What does React.render return ? Component Instance or Component class?

Tags: reactjs, terminology

In [this](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/fcb1b6ab493b0c77d589) gist, in this line `React.render = (ReactElement, HTMLElement | SVGElement) => ReactComponent;`

What does `ReactComponent` refer to ? An [instance or a class](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html) ?

Reason for asking: I am trying to create a concept map that visualises React terminology (as shown below).

[image]

Comment: Short answer, it returns component instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR React.render returns a ReactComponent instance**

---

As you have written, React.render accepts two arguments. It is important to understand their meaning. This bit is confusing so please bear with me.

1) ReactElement - is a virtual dom instance. Sometimes this instance maps to native DOM elements such as 'div', sometimes it maps to ReactComponent instance such as `MyComponent` that encapsulates a tree of other ReactElements. You see the recursion here?

```
ReactElement -> Tree<ReactComponent returns ReactElement -> Tree<ReactComponent returns ReactElement>>
```

Now, let's create a virtual dom instance

```
const virtualElement = React.createElement('MyComponent');
```

2) The second arguments is a native DOM element to render the virtualElement into.

Basically what React.render does is to translate the `virtualElement` in native DOM element and insert it into the native DOM element specified as second argument in the React.render function.

---

**As a result, React.render returns a ReactComponent instance (stateful representation of encapsulated ReactElement trees).**

I think you might be a little frustrated by the notation, but it makes perfect sense. Think of it in terms of Java for example:

```
function Person getPerson() { 
  return new Person();
}
```

See, the signature of the function doesn't specify `PersonInstance` as return value, but rather `Person`.

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks ! What does `React.createClass` return then ? What type ? In this terminology : https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/fcb1b6ab493b0c77d589#formal-type-definitions ? Is it `type ReactClass<TProps> = (TProps) => ReactComponent<TProps>;` ?

Comment: Generic ReactComponent Instance again of type TProps